# Gumbel distribution convergence

Tags: probability, statistics

$X_1,X_2,\ldots$ IID, so that $X_i\sim E(\lambda)$. Therefore $\mathbf{P}(X_i>t)=\exp(-\lambda t)$ if $t\geqslant 0$. We denote $M_n=\max\{X_1,\ldots ,X_n\}$ and I want to prove that
$$M_n-\frac{\ln n}\lambda \overset{D}\to Y,$$
where $Y\sim G_\lambda$, $G_\lambda (t)=\exp(-e^{-\lambda t}), \ t\in \mathbb{R}, \ \lambda >0$.

I don't know how to deal with $M_n$. Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2262284/321264

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\mathrm{Pr}\left(M_n-\frac{\ln n}{\lambda}>t\right)=\mathrm{Pr}\left(X_1>t+\frac{\ln n}{\lambda}\right)^n=\mathrm{exp}\left(-\lambda n(t+\ln n/\lambda)\right)
$$
it follows that
$$
\lim_n\mathrm{Pr}\left(M_n-\frac{\ln n}{\lambda}\le t\right)=1- \mathrm{exp}\left(-\lim_n (\lambda nt + n\ln n)\right)=1
$$
whenever $t>0$. Are you sure about the text?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Because the maximum of several quantities is less than a number if and only if each quantity is less than the number, you have $\Bbb P[M_n\le x]=[1-\exp(-\lambda x)]^n$.