# Convergence in Distribution of the maximum of a sequence.

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I've come across this problem which has completely stumped me. It goes as follows:

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$. Let $M_n$ denote max{$X_1,...,X_n $}. Show there exists a random variable $Z$ such that $M_n - \frac{1}{\lambda} \log (n) $ converges in distribution to $Z$.

Now this problem seems really hard, so I tried proving it for convergence in probability to see if that would work and imply convergence in distribution, but I couldn't get very far. Moreover, calculating the expectations also seems non-trivial due to the fact that it would be hard to integrate $M_n = \frac{1}{\lambda} \log n$.

Any suggestions and ways to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for a long time. Should I try using the Skorohod equivalent statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately we do not have convergence in probability, so that approach is not going to succeed. The basic trick is to note that $M_n\le a$ if and only if $X_i\le a$ for each $i=1,\ldots,n$ and then use independence:
$$P(M_n-\tfrac1\lambda\log n\le x)=P(M_n\le\tfrac1\lambda\log n+x)=\prod_{i=1}^nP(X_i\le\tfrac1\lambda\log n+x).$$
Now remembering that $P(X_i\le a)=1-e^{-\lambda a}$, we find
$$P(M_n-\tfrac1\lambda\log n\le x)=\left(1-e^{-\lambda(\frac1\lambda\log n+x)}\right)^n=\left(1-\frac{e^{-\lambda x}}n\right)^n\to e^{-e^{-\lambda x}}$$
as $n\to\infty$. Hence $M_n\to Z$ in distribution where $P(Z\le x)=e^{-e^{-\lambda x}}$.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was quite an elegant response. I think I lacked a proper understanding of convergence in distribution. You clarified it a lot for me I think. I didn't realise that I just had to show convergence of the cdf.

Comment: That makes sense, and in that case I think trying a few more exercises like this is a good idea! There are other ways to check convergence in distribution, too: you can use convergence of the characteristic function, or look into something called the Portmanteau theorem.

Comment: By the way, the distribution of $Z$ is the [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) with parameters $\mu=0$ and $\beta=1/\lambda$.

Comment: Would anyone be kind to explain more about the statement "Unfortunately we do not have convergence in probability"?

Comment: @MathArt https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables